# Accent on the word "a" in 1909 Reina Valera Bible

Tags: ortografía, acentuación

I was reading the 1909 Reina Valera Bible, and I noticed that in it the word "a" has an accent, for example:

> Y llamó Dios á la seca Tierra, y á la reunión de las aguas llamó Mares: y vió Dios que era bueno.

Why is this? Is it an old rule of Spanish?

---

Estaba leyendo la Biblia Reina Valera de 1909, y me di cuenta de que la palabra "a" lleva acento. Por ejemplo:

> Y llamó Dios á la seca Tierra, y á la reunión de las aguas llamó Mares: y vió Dios que era bueno.

¿Por qué? ¿Es una regla antigua del español?

Comment: I looked up in my Spanish Bible, an RV1960 and, sure enough, the accent is gone from the "a".  It also had "lo seco" instead of "la seca".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, antes la preposición *a* (y el coordinador *o*) se escribía con tilde siempre.  Esta practica se dejó a principios del siglo XX si recuerdo bien con la 14.ª edición del *Diccionario de la lengua española* publicado por la RAE en 1914.  Hubo algunas gramáticas que fueron publicadas entre esta y la 13.ª de 1899, así que en cualquier de estas hallaríamos el primer momento en que se dictó la forma sin tilde.

En aquel entonces (bueno, incluso hasta 2010) se usaban tildes no solo para indicar la acentuación y silabificación sino también por razones como distinción de palabras (*solo* y *sólo*) o para mejorar la visibilidad (el coordinador *ó* también perdió su tilde en el siglo XX excepto entre cifras porque se suponía que se lo podía confundir por el cero, fue en 2010 que se le quitó por completo la tilde)