# ¿Existe o existió algún verbo cuya conjugación incluya la forma "á"?

Tags: verbos, historia, preposiciones, palabras-raras

Estaba trasteando un poco con las opciones de Google Ngram, y me ha salido esta gráfica:

[image: formas verbales que suelen preceder a la expresión "las consecuencias"]

En Ngram, los asteriscos funcionan como comodines, permitiendo buscar una secuencia de palabras precedida por otra cualquiera. El afijo `_VERB` limita los valores del comodín, haciendo que solo muestre resultados en los que se corresponda con un verbo.

Según esto, hasta ~1910 lo más habitual era que la frase "las consecuencias" fuese precedida del verbo "á": *"á las consecuencias"*.

¿Qué verbo sería este? ¿Quizá un equivalente de "ha" pero mal escrito?
¿O tal vez es un error de Ngram, y esto no es un verbo sino la preposición "a" con tilde?

Comment: No es ningún verbo. Hasta más o menos la fecha que comentas la preposición "a" ha llevado tilde: "á" (y en la época de Cervantes incluso se podría ver "à").

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15244/accent-on-the-word-a-in-1909-reina-valera-bible

Comment: 3a persona indicativo futuro simple -er, -ir e.j. *irá, comerá*; 2a persona voseo imperativo -ar (y *ir*) e.j. *hablá, andá* ? E.g. `... enfrentará las consecuencias...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La preposición *a* ha llevado tilde durante la mayor parte de su historia. La eliminación de la tilde se produjo hace relativamente poco tiempo. Observa la definición en el *Academia usual* de 1899:

> **Á.** (Del lat. *ad* ó *ab*.) prep. Denota el complemento de la acción del verbo [...].

Y a continuación la definición en el *Academia usual* de 1914:

> **A.** (Del lat. *ad.*) prep. Denota el complemento de la acción del verbo [...].

Como ves, las fechas cuadran con ese descenso brusco del uso de *á* hacia 1910. Y antes que eso se usó con la tilde grave, como atestigua el *Autoridades* de 1726:

[image: à]

Ejemplos del CORDE:

> *En cuanto á las consecuencias políticas que habían de reportar los patentes errores de la censura, bien se demostraban en el sentido de la dimisión de Gamazo.*
>
> Vidal Fité, "Las desdichas de la patria", 1899 (España).

El caso más tardío de "á las consecuencias" en el CORDE es de 1913, que concuerda con las fechas. En cuanto al cambio exacto, estoy tratando de buscarlo pero debió ser en alguna de las ediciones del *Prontuario de ortografía castellana en preguntas y respuestas* de la RAE. Al parecer hubo ediciones de dicho prontuario en 1900, 1901, 1903, 1905, 1907, 1909, 1911 y 1913, entre otros años, pero cito estos porque son las ediciones publicadas entre las dos ediciones del DLE citadas arriba. En una de ellas se debió de reflejar la eliminación de la tilde en la preposición *á* (y la conjunción *ó*, ya puestos).

Yo diría que pudo ser la edición de 1907, la última justo antes de que la gráfica del uso de las preposiciones diese el cambiazo, o incluso la de 1909:

[image: Cambiazo]